# How to Reduce This Block of Code

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, selenium

I'm completely new to Python and was just made aware of list comprehension, which is quite impressive. I'm wondering if there are similar ways to reduce the following `if` statement.

```
if len(browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//span[@gogo-test="backers"]')) > 0:
    backers = [sub for sub in browser.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@gogo-test="backers"]').text.split() if sub.isdigit()][0]
```

Ideally, I'd like to use `backers = [sub for sub in browser.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@gogo-test="backers"]').text.split() if sub.isdigit()][0]`, but, unlike Scrapy, Selenium doesn't return `None` if it doesn't find anything, and there will certainly be instances where `browser.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@gogo-test="backers"]')` doesn't exist.

Thanks

Comment: There is a way to do it (you can put two conditions in the list comprehension by gluing them with an `and`, but I would suggest against it, as it would get quite cumbersome. What you have right now is just fine.

Comment: @RushabhMehta but the `for` loop in the list comprehension is dependent on whether or not `browser.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@gogo-test="backers"]')` exists in the first place??

Comment: That actually may improve the situation. Try dropping the if clause altogether. See what you get! I have a suspicion that if len = 0, then backers will be an empty list

Comment: So, run this `backers = [sub for sub in browser.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@gogo-test="backers"]').text.split() if sub.isdigit()]`, then see what it has. Don't select the first element just yet, cuz it may not exist.

Comment: @RushabhMehta sure, i guess i'll try dropping the `[0]`

Comment: Did that do the trick?

Comment: @RushabhMehta yeah, doesn't work as i suspected. `NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: ` same exception i receive when the element doesn't exist.

Comment: welp, nvm. I honestly don't think what you have to start is all that bad. Just stick with that

Comment: @RushabhMehta ahh the extra line of code due to the `if` statement is bugging me, especially since you would only need the one liner in Scrapy since Scrapy would simply return `None` if the element did not exist :(

Comment: I will throw my 5 cents. Why do you want to write everything in one row? It will be very hard to debug this and to read in the future. Lets say in 2-3 months you will not remember what exactly this line does and it will take relative much time to debug such code. The elegant code IMO isn't a code in line - but a simple to read and understand, like you reading a book. Of course, if it possible to write compact readable code it is always good. In this case it is already compact

Comment: @AndreiSuvorkov the goal isn't necessarily one line, but a simple, readable one liner, as you've suggested.

Answer (score 1):

You would be allow to reduce your code block by using Page-Object-Model which is a common Selenium convention:

```
if  page.get_spans_array_size() > 0:
    backers = [sub for sub in  page.get_spans_array() if sub.isdigit()][0]
```

Page code:

```
class Page:

    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.driver = driver

    def get_spans_array_size(self):
        return len(
                   ## self.driver.find..  )

    def get_spans_array(self):
        return ## self.driver.find..
```

I have a python example of POM in my open source project:
https://github.com/AutomatedOwl/selenium-python-pom-example

Comment: can you link to the documentation for `get_spans_array`?

Comment: You should create it in separate page class. See the Page class in my example for how getting it done.

Comment: are you talking about `class Site88Page` on your git??

Comment: Yes it's just an example of page class in python. There are many on GitHub.

Comment: yeah, i don't believe that will work in my script, and i'm still not sure how that relates to the `get_spans_array_size()` method?

Comment: See revised answer

Comment: yeah, i just read it. why is a page class even necessary? couldn't i just embed the `def` functions directly into my current script? also, i'm not sure creating an entirely different class in order to reduce the length of the condition of the `if` statement by a handful of characters is really worth it...

Comment: It makes your Page code reusable and your overall code much more efficient and cleaner. And yes it also reduces the code block you asked about. The design of your tests is up only to you. Imo writing Selenium without pom is total mess.

Comment: who knows. if i run into the same issue again down the road, perhaps i'll implement a page class, but for one instance...

Comment: would using the `if` statement instead of a `try-except` cause memory leakage in the sense that you'd be creating all of these empty lists?

Answer (score 0):

```
backers = [sub for sub in browser.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@gogo-test="backers"]').text.split() if sub.isdigit()]
backers = backers[0] if len(backers) > 0 else None
```

It is already very short, few improvements possible:) Or

```
backers = list(filter(lambda sub: sub.isdigit(),
                      browser.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@gogo-test="backers"]').text.split()
               ))

backers = backers[0] if len(backers) > 0 else None
```

Or with regular expressions:

```
import re
backers = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//span[@gogo-test="backers"]')
backers = backers[0].text if len(backers) > 0 else ''
backers = re.findall('(\d+)', backers)
```

Comment: hm.. yeah, i don't see how those suggestions would be in any way reductions :/

Comment: As I mentioned, there is almost nothing to reduce. As I understand, you just need to extract numbers from a string. Than regex, I'll append this solution to answer. The object-oriented solution would be great for a more complicated case. Also it does `browser.find_elements_by_xpath('...')` operation twice.

Comment: get_elementS_... returns the list if empty and finds all,  get_element _... raises Element Not Found error to handle further